# Give access to Directus 9 (install on my local computer) from outside my network

Tags: http, nginx, directus, ufw

I created a Directus 9 + my SQL database project on my personal computer.

The project runs on localhost: 8055

I want to give access to the Directus administration interface to remote users and external to my network.

My private ip address is yyy.yyy.y.yy
My public ip address is xx.xxx.xx.xx

I have configured Nginx and it works fine as long as I am local. That is to say on two different computers, I manage to connect to the Directus administration interface. Except that the two stations are connected to the same WIFI.

Regarding the firewall, here is what I have:

[image: Firewall configuration]

Nginx configuration:

[image: Nginx configuration]

How can I connect to my application which is started on my local computer from any other external computer ?

I tell myself that there is a syntax like this: http: //xx.xxx.xx.xx/yyy.yyy.y.yy

thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The incident has just been resolved.
There were restrictions on my internet service provider.
I had to authorize them HTTPS calls on port 443 and secure Nginx with Let's Encrypt.
All of them are working well.